# (How) Can I place a with sql query in a table value function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to put the following with query as a return of a table value function.

```
;with org as (
   select ID
   from ORG_UNIT
   where id = @ID_ORG_UNIT
   union all
   select PARENT_ID
   from ORG_UNIT c
     join org p on p.ID = c.id
) 
select * from org
```

I already tried to create such a function however I'm now resorting to stored procedure in despair...

Is it possible to create a function to return this result?

Comment: Remove the starting semicolon.

Comment: Why can't you just change this to `select * from (cte sql code here)` ?

Comment: @rs. mind guive an example?

Comment: @GSerg that guives two errors, msg 156, level 15, state 1 and msg 319, level 15, state 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create function test_func(@ID_ORG_UNIT int)
returns table
as
return (
  with org as (
     select ID
     from ORG_UNIT
     where id = @ID_ORG_UNIT
     union all
     select PARENT_ID
     from ORG_UNIT c
       join org p on p.ID = c.id
  ) 
  select * from org   
);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1447/1)